# Json POST request works in java but not PHP?

Tags: java, php, curl

I have an odd problem that i cannot seem to solve at all. We have a rest service that is supposed to accept submission data as a JSON object.

I have been going round in circles using curl. The command works with any service off the corporate network, and any EXTERNAL one when i use the curl proxy option but nothing is accessible (get or post) on the internal network. I always get a "false" comming back  as response. Here is the PHP code:

---

```
$data_string =  "{\"fashionSignups\":[{\"corporateBrandId\":0,\"vendorId\":null,\"countryCode\":\"pt\",\"languageCode\":\"pt\",\"email\":\"test@ytDessddefwwt.com\",\"genderCode\":0,\"hasChildren\":0,\"zipcode\":\"12345\"}]}";
$ch = curl_init('http://xxx.xxx.com/fashionnewssignup');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "http://proxy.xxxx.com");
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, "8080");
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, CRED);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 50);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump( curl_getinfo($ch) ) . '<br/>';
echo curl_errno($ch) . '<br/>';
echo curl_error($ch) . '<br/>';
//close connection
curl_close($ch);
var_dump ($result);
die;
```

---

### and it's output:

```
array(26) {
  'url' =>
  string(59) "http://xxx.xxx.com/fashionnewssignup"
  'content_type' =>
  NULL
  'http_code' =>
  int(0)
  'header_size' =>
  int(0)
  'request_size' =>
  int(251)
  'filetime' =>
  int(-1)
  'ssl_verify_result' =>
  int(0)
  'redirect_count' =>
  int(0)
  'total_time' =>
  double(0.031)
  'namelookup_time' =>
  double(0)
  'connect_time' =>
  double(0.016)
  'pretransfer_time' =>
  double(0.016)
  'size_upload' =>
  double(0)
  'size_download' =>
  double(0)
  'speed_download' =>
  double(0)
  'speed_upload' =>
  double(0)
  'download_content_length' =>
  double(-1)
  'upload_content_length' =>
  double(-1)
  'starttransfer_time' =>
  double(0.031)
  'redirect_time' =>
  double(0)
  'redirect_url' =>
  string(0) ""
  'primary_ip' =>
  string(12) "XX.XX.XXX.12"
  'certinfo' =>
  array(0) {
  }
  'primary_port' =>
  int(1080)
  'local_ip' =>
  string(13) "XX.XX.XXX.196"
  'local_port' =>
  int(56107)
}
52<br/>Empty reply from server<br/>C:\xampp\htdocs\at\test.php:46:
bool(false)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

---

"Empty reply from server" 52 is what i get regardless of what URL i feed in. As i said above this code works fine off the network with other sites.

A git-bash curl gives this:

```
    curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"fashionNewsSignups":[{"                                    corporateBrandId":0,"vendorId":null,"countryCode":"pt","languageCode":"pt","emai                                    l":"test@ytDessddefwwt.com","genderCode":0,"hasChildren":0,"zipcode":"12345"}]}'                                     http://xxx.xxx.com/fashionnewssignup
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
    100   184    0     0  100   184      0   5935 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 12266 
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

**The strange part is, when i try the same thing in JAVA on the same machine on the same network using this code, it works 100% fine, no proxy or anything required.**

This JAVA code works:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

try {
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://xxx.xxx.com/fashionnewssignup");
    StringEntity params =new StringEntity("{\"fashionSignups\":[{\"corporateBrandId\":0,\"vendorId\":null,\"countryCode\":\"pt\",\"languageCode\":\"pt\",\"email\":\"test@ytDessddefwwt.com\",\"genderCode\":0,\"hasChildren\":0,\"zipcode\":\"12345\"}]}");
    request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    request.setEntity(params);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    String s = response.getStatusLine()+" " + response.toString();
    System.out.println(s);
}catch (Exception ex) {
    // handle exception here
} finally {
    httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}
```

Anyone know what i am doing wrong? The service i am trying to access is written in JAVA if that is important :/

Comment: PS: I have tried the PHP both running in command line and as an endpoint on my XAMPP. Result is the same. I don't understand how the JAVA is working though :/

Answer (score 0):

```
$data_string =  '{"fashionSignups":[{"corporateBrandId":0,"vendorId":null,"countryCode":"pt","languageCode":"pt","email":"test@ytDessddefwwt.com","genderCode":0,"hasChildren":0,"zipcode":"12345"}]}';

$data_string = json_decode($data_string,true);
```

$data_string is a string in your case, while your content-type is JSON
So the above code will convert your string to a JSON Object and it should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, but that cannot be right because every example i have seen converts a php array into a json string using json_encode before sending it in. That string is actually the output from an encoding.
Also, this code works with another JSON based rest system outside the network. 

Doing this gives me the error:
"PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\at\test.php on line 14"
Line 14 being this:
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);

Every example i have seen "post json using curl" says it must be json-encoded (that string is that result from encode)

Comment: Also if there was a poblem with the JSON i would get a 40x server error, not the error  "(52) Empty reply from server".

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved in the end, it was down to needing this line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROXY , 'xxx.xxx.com');
```

for anyone having the same issue :)

I did not try it because it was not in the list of constants in curl_d.php, and intelliJ reports that the "constant is undefined"
... but it works?!? :o
-who knew lol.

Comment: then send JetBrains a bugreport, its a bug in IntelliJ